# XCode crashes on start up

Tags: xcode6

Yes, this happens to people. Yes, I've looked at all the solutions.

This is different.

XCode starts and there is no error message, it just freezes. This is the screen I get: [image]

That's it. No errors. I can't interact with it, I can't close it. The only thing I can do is use Show All Windows. There are five and yes I don't need them all (never did! don't know why I have them) but I can't close any of them. To get rid of it I need to do a hard reset.

I've tried deleting the library file in Finder as this was one of the solutions.

Nope.

Anyone any ideas?

I think it's XCode 6 (the latest) but I can't tell because I can't access the menu.

Comment: Maybe try installing the newest beta ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scouring Stackoverflow for ways to clear the startup process.

You hold cmd+shift when you start XCode - ONLY from the task bar, this does NOT work if you go into the Applications folder - and it will load blank.

Then you can load your project.